# Why are we so technical?

Tags: discussion

And by we, I mean you, not me, you!

Seriously, **we are holding this question** [How to change TB mega menu name dynamically?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/183895/how-to-change-tb-mega-menu-name-dynamically?noredirect=1#comment223066_183895)

> I have used the Megamenu module and create a menu 'login', now when
>   user is logged-in, I want to change the name to logout.
>
> Is it possible?

**Because he didn't mention that he also needs to change the url link?**

[image: Screenshot]

Really, you want me to edit the question? While I am at it, should I also improve the answer by mentioning that he needs to have a database?

Some of the other voters, perhaps, put it on hold in light of the asker's comments on the answer.

However, if you put it on hold based on no mention of url link, you are figuratively driving me crazy, there is a chance you've literally driven me crazy.

It's not just me, is it?

Answer (score 7):

> Why are we so technical?

Easy - the difference between being able to provide an answer to a question that's potentially ambiguous, and one that's explicit, is huge. Often those seemingly insignificant technicalities actually change the course of the entire question.

Similarly, people often think they want to do something one way because they're not aware of a better/easier way. When we know some background and motivation around the problem, it's much easier to give sound advice.

By a twist of fate, this particular case has proven itself; if you look at the comment from the OP on the answer:

> Thanks for useful answer, but this work if use the drupal login, but we use the login from API and store the session if successful authentication occurs, so assume that user is login if session have a value and unset this session on logout.

That info, which is critical to providing an answer to the question the OP *wanted* to ask, but didn't, was missing from the post. I understand you asked this meta question based on a different clarification that was sought from the OP, but I think the point has been well made by how that whole question played out.

I don't know if this harsh, it's just my opinion, but I don't see any reason why the OP can't edit the post to clarify exactly what they need the free, expert advice for. I also don't see any problem with members of the community trying to prise that information out of users. It's kinda how this is supposed to work.